# Why LINQ complained on the CAPITAL range variable?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Why complained? I'm almost BANG my head on wall.
Sometimes it allowed capital. Strange!!! Can someone explain?

[image]

Comment: It's not just LINQ. All C# identifiers are case-sensitive.. `CRM` and `crm` are different variables.

Comment: Is `CRM` a name of some other class or a package that may be in the current scope?

Comment: Yes i know is case-sensitive, but why complained? it's only allow me to use lower case variable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight NO, definitely no "CRM" variable

Comment: @tsohtan no offense, but are you **absolutely** sure that you don't have a local variable called `CRM` elsewhere in that function? The error message is pretty explicitly saying that you do..

Comment: @Blorgbeard, dasblinkenlight, Yes, your both right.It is because of unwanted code leave at the bottom for reference which i'm just focused on the top to build the query. Fool myself! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

suppose that there are CRM variable in function`s scope.